# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, edubuntu

I have a brand new dell inspiron 5559,  4gb ram, uefi , with pre installed Ubuntu.
I tried to install a version of edubuntu 14.04 64 bit with live cd in uefi mode, it is showing a dialog box like ,

```
"the dell recovery media can be used to restore the original factory software. It is recommended you backup all important data before Running this tool" 
"Error this recover media only functions on dell and alienware systems "
```

The only available  option is "quit"

When I am tried to install in legacy mode it's showing that Ubuntu is having an internal error. 
(I think it is with the installer, ubiquity),

```
 problem type -  crash
title - ubiquity crashed with 'try modprobe' efivars as root in fetch_o
```

Disk have 4 partitions

```
Sda1 esp partition 500 mb fat    
Sda2 os partition 3.2 gb fat     
Sda3 filesysytem partition 988 gb ext4    
Sda4 swap partition 8.4 gb
```

Someone plz suggest me the steps to solve my problems, 
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Something is wrong with your installation cd or usb....make a new one

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot?  Your disk has an ESP partition, so I assume that you should be using EUFI in  bios, and you may need to turn off safe mode booting.

Comment: Lewis4u    , the problem is not with the cd, I tried the CD in another desktop &  it's showing the window for installation.

Comment: Charles green,   I am not trying for dual boot, What I want is a edubuntu 14.04. I have selected  UEFI &  disabled "secure boot". But no use,  it's showing that same old dialogue box like "this recovery media only functions on dell and alienware systems"..  (btw is secure boot same as safe boot??)

Comment: I think the problem is with dell, it's recovery media tool, that why it's showing a message like this "the dell recovery media can be used to restore the original factory software. It is recommended you backup all important data before Running this tool" 
"Error this recover media only functions on dell and alienware systems"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions. 
I got a solution for my problem, but there may be some perfect answers for my problem.

What I did is booted a live windows cd &  reached the point where to install Windows on HDD. I formated the entire hard disk and quit the windows installation procedure. 
Now I have a fresh HDD (1tb free space). 
Then tried installing Ubuntu 64 bit in uefi mode, the installation process was perfectly completed and have my edubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu software center and search for "dell recovery " package and remove it.Then boot from USB ;it will work smoothly. I think you can reinstall Dell recovery after new installations